# Unable to open datetimepicker in angular js

Tags: angularjs, datetimepicker

below is the html code to open a datetimepicker calender

```
 <div class="input-group date"
data-datetimepicker="datetimepicker"
 data-date-format="YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm AM/PM"  >
 <input id="mypicker" class="form-control" type="text"
placeholder=""ng-model="note.remainder"/> <span
class="input-group-addon"> <span id="mypicker"
class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"  > </span>
</span>
</div>
```

css link::

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
```

app.js::

```
var app = angular.module('ToDoApp',
    [ 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngSanitize' ,'ui.bootstrap.datepicker']);
```

Comment: `bootstrap.min.js` that doesn't look like `ui-bootstrap.min.js`. You are mixing bootstrap with [ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) (that you should be using with `ui.router`)

Answer (score 0):

For a working uib-datepicker you need this scripts:

- angular.js
- ui-bootstrap.js (or the script only for the datepicker)

and/or

- ui-bootstrap-tpls.js

Based on your question, you did not include any of this.

Comment: i have already included these links <script type="text/javascript"
 src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>

Comment: @RaginPatil First must be the angular.js script and then all the others

Comment: yes i have included the links in the same order the way u said

Comment: @RaginiPatil update your question with relevant scripts and their versions

Answer (score 0):

use `input type` as `date` instead of `text` according to `html5`

```
<input type='date'>
```

Comment: Ragini used the wrong bootstrap, it should be a directory in the first place: `<div uib-datepicker ng-model="dt" datepicker-options="options"></div>`

Comment: by using <input type='date'> we get only date how to get date as well as time..??